# long/int to UINT64 conversion and back to long on C# - when can I lose data?

Tags: c#, c++

I have C++ server which sends me data to C# client. The server reads some values from database.
It has parser used for serializing data to be sent over network which can only send unsigned numbers - e.g. `uint64`.

But in the database I believe one value it sends me has type `int/long`. So after reading from database probably it casts it to `uint64`.

On the C# side I do following with that number

```
balance = unchecked((long)answer.Find(ModuleGlobals.TAG_TI_BALANCE).Get_QWORD());
```

where balance is of type `long`. But Get_QWORD on C# returns `ulong` - as I said parser only works with unsigned numbers.

**So in what situations can I lose data above?** Or I will always end up with the data that server sent me? (even in case of negative integers?)

---

Basically the flow is like this I guess

***int/long --> converted/cast to uint64 by server --> Send over network --> Parsed as ulong --> Cast to long (as I showed in my code)***

Comment: Will the server be sending negative numbers? If not, then I don't think you'll be loosing any data.

Comment: @AustinWBryan It might but before sending it is casting it to uint64

Comment: That's a rather feeble network.  But no, these kind of casts don't change the bits of the value, only the interpretation of the bits.  The only risk factor is the order of the bytes, big-endian vs little-endian.  You can never not notice that problem.

Comment: @HansPassant Endianness has been taken care of

Answer (score 0):

Needs revision as question changed.

---

Change it to

```
balance = unchecked((int)answer.Find(ModuleGlobals.TAG_TI_BALANCE).Get_QWORD());`
```

`C#`'s `long` is set at 64-bit. `C++`'s `long` varies. If both are same size (and same representation) everything is fine.

But on Windows, C++'s `long` is 32-bit. So, you are going to lose the sign-bit on negative numbers. For example sending `-1` from the C++ front will give you a `0xFFFFffff` in C#. To get `0xFFFFffff` back to `-1` again, you have to cast it to a same size type, which is `int`.

But as you see this still assumes a certain size of `long` in your C++ code (which is Ok if you only target Windows). If you have access to the C++ code, better change `long` to a fixed size type like `uint64_t` from `<cstdint>` and cast it to `long` on the C# side as you were doing.

Comment: Thanks but no I meant on C++ is it cast to uint64 - so what happens in this case?

Comment: @user200312 C++ compilers on Windows treat `unsigned long` as 32-bit. So in order to have everything go smooth, have the same size data type on both sides (C++'s `long` ≠ C#'s `long`).

Comment: Yes but I checked and on C++ UINT64 is used

Comment: You sure the database stores `INT`s and `LONG`s and only sends out `UINT64`s?

Comment: I was told it is NUMBER type in ORACLE database - but there will be no fixed point numbers stored there like 1.2 only whole numbers. When sent over network it is cast to UINT64 because the serializer only supports unsigned integers

Comment: Basically yes I am sure server always sends numbers as UINT64 because parser supports only that - but in database it can be long